# Using Entity Framework to query external DB without defining an edmx file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have the following:-

1. Asp.net mvc5 web application.
2. Entity framework version 6.

Now I have mapped the sql server tables inside my asp.net mvc5 using the ado.net entity framework , which created an edmx file.
But now I want to query an external database to retrieve some info from it, I know that I can map the external DB and create another edmx file inside my application. but I do not want to depend my application on the external DB , because the external DB might be replaced by our company in the future.

So is there a way to query external DB using EF ? i tried using DbSet.SqlQuery but seems I can only query my own database with it.

Can anyone advice on this please

Comment: What about using code first with an existing db? No need to create a .edmx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj200620.aspx

Comment: You can create a stored procedure in your mapped db and access it through the application using EF. The stored procedure will access your external DB to fetch data required by you.
In this way your application will only be dependent on your map DB.
Hope this helps.

Comment: @SimranjeetSingh ok thanks , but can I instead of using Stored Procedures to query externla DB using DbSet.SqlQuery ?

Comment: If you truly want a "disconnected" way of doing things you'd just use the old ADO.NET approach by building a connection string, query string, opening a SqlConnection and executing a SqlCommand. Though, the obvious downside is that your results won't be mapped to an object. Really the best way of doing it is creating a good service/repo layer such that if your external DB does go away you only have to replace your data layer and everything would function the same way.

Comment: @Shoe thanks for the reply, so what is the approach you recommend for creating a good service/repo layer ? and the approach i was proposing is to use DbSet.SqlQuery method which will run queries that return entity types,, but not sure if i can use the DbSet.SqlQuery provided by EF to query external DB, as i can use it to query my edmx entities and the result will be automatically mapped to my objects .

Comment: That won't work because it will only hit the context that the DbSet is connected to. You need to establish a new connection and query it from there. If it's not mapped into EF then you can't use EF to query it. There are a lot of examples of how to implement the repo pattern in MVC and it's too much to explain in a comment.

Comment: I am using the Repository pattern in my asp.net mvc web application. so you mean i can write a stored procedure which retrieve the data from external database , and then use EF to execute the stored procedure ?

Comment: No, because your stored procedure will have to be mapped into EF anyway and your stored proc mapping will only "see" the DB connection to your main source, not the "rider" DB that you are hoping to connect to. If you want to use a stored proc and want it independent of EF you have to use classic ADO.